# How can I access the standard viewForHeaderInSection for a tableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got an indexed UITableView with individual sections. I would like to use a different background color for the header views in each section. I know I can completely roll my own view by implementing tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: (for example, see [question # 2898361](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898361/how-to-recreate-the-default-uiview-the-same-as-the-default-tableviewviewforheade)), but that seems to be "too much work" to me - the standard view looks fine, I would just have to change its background color.

But how do I access this standard view? I can't use `[super tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:]` because this is a question of implementing a protocol and not an issue of inheritance. Any other way I can get the standard view?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm almost certain you can't do this easily. I used one of my tech support request on my dev account recently asking about altering the background and borders of UITableView sections. The apple engineer told me that this really wasn't an easy thing to do, and even if you managed to do it, you would probably affect performance. He also pointed me to cocoawithlove and an article about editing uitableviews:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/adding-shadow-effects-to-uitableview.html

Really, creating your own header isn't that much effort. Below is some code I pulled out of one of my projects - it was commented out, so might not work straight away - but you can get the idea:

```
 - (CAGradientLayer *) greyGradient {
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);

    UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:240.0f/255.0f green:240.0f/255.0f blue:240.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

    [gradient setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)color1.CGColor, (id)color2.CGColor, nil]];
    return gradient;
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds); 
    CGFloat height = [self tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section];
    UIView *container = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)] autorelease];
    container.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    container.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [self greyGradient];
    gradient.frame = container.bounds;
    [container.layer addSublayer:gradient];

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12,0,width,height)] autorelease];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.font= [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:19.0f];
    headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    NSString *title = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    headerLabel.text = title;
    return container;
}
```

Make sure to

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

By the way... this isn't supposed to mimic the look of the standard headers - its just an example. But I'm sure with a bit of trial and error you could alter this to mimic the standard ones and then change the colors slightly.

Comment: There seems to be missing something in your text .. #import what? Probably some core animation stuff?

Comment: Oh yeah, it was QuartzCore for using the CAGradientLayer - I'll add it to post. Thanks

Comment: It's also missing [container addSubview:headerLabel], and really it's better if you do something like this:  
 CGFloat width = tableView.bounds.size.width;
 CGFloat height = [self tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section];
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];

Comment: I did say "Below is some code I pulled out of one of my projects - it was commented out". But you're right, that is the correct way to do that. I also now like to use the CGRect macros: CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds);

Answer (score 5):

Although the other answers correctly point out you cannot access the default view to make simple modifications to it, if you have nothing to customize for a particular section header, you can return `nil` from `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and the table view will use the default view.

This is helpful if you only need to customize some of your headers.

For whatever reason this is [undocumented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW3).

Answer (score 1):

There is one problem with @bandejapalsa solution: the previous cell's  separator is still visible with this implementation where as it is not on the default iOS sectionHeaderView. The solution I found was to use a CALayer and offset it by 1 pix. The image needs to be 1pix taller than the view frame itself.

```
// Create the view for the header
CGRect aFrame =CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.contentSize.width, IMIUICustomisation.sectionHeaderViewHeight);
UIView * aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
aView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;

// Create a stretchable image for the background that emulates the default gradient, only in green
UIImage *viewBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenheader.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];

// Cannot set this image directly as the background of the cell because
// the background needs to be offset by 1pix at the top to cover the previous cell border (Alex Deplov's requirement ^_^)
CALayer *backgroungLayer = [CALayer layer];

backgroungLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, -1, tableView.contentSize.width, IMIUICustomisation.sectionHeaderViewHeight+1);
backgroungLayer.contents = (id) viewBackgroundImage.CGImage;
backgroungLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
backgroungLayer.opacity = 0.9;
[aView.layer addSublayer:backgroungLayer];

// Take care of the section title now
UILabel *aTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 0, aView.bounds.size.width-10, aView.bounds.size.height)];
aTitle.text = [delegate tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
aTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
aTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
aTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor;

// Text shadow
aTitle.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
aTitle.layer.shadowRadius = .2;
aTitle.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
aTitle.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
aTitle.layer.shadowColor = IMIUICustomisation.selectedElementTextShadowColor.CGColor;
[aView addSubview:aTitle];

return aView;
```